# `make install` Fails Inside Docker

Tags: docker, perl, makefile, debian-jessie, jmap

I'm trying to build a docker image for a JMAP Proxy named [`jmap-perl`](https://github.com/jmapio/jmap-perl).

The [documentation](https://github.com/jmapio/jmap-perl/blob/master/INSTALL) states that it targets `Debian Jessie` by default, so I have created the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie

# Port to expose.
EXPOSE 80

# Add all files in current directory
# to a new folder named `jmap-perl`
# in Debian Jessie's `/` folder.
ADD . / ./jmap-perl/

# Install `build-essential` (needed for `make install`) and `perl`.
# `apt-get update` is required to install `build-essential`.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    perl

# Navigate to our new folder and run `make install`.
RUN cd /jmap-perl
RUN make install

# Run the scripts needed by the server.
CMD ["perl bin/apiendpoint.pl && perl bin/server.pl"]
```

I have added this `Dockerfile` to the project's root folder and copied everything to our Docker server.

On our Docker server, I am running the below commands:

```
cd jmap-perl
docker build -t jmap-perl:latest .
```

Everything goes well until it hits the `make install` command which produces the following error:

```
Step 6/7 : RUN make install
---> Running in 6209e8b71062
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
The command '/bin/sh -c make install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

What puzzles me is that the `Makefile` inside the project's root directory already contains a section for `install: all`.

Is there anything I need to change in the `Makefile` or the steps I'm running in my `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things to take note here:

1. For this `ADD . / ./jmap-perl/`, you should use COPY instead of ADD: `COPY . /jmap-perl/`
2. Instead of using `RUN cd /jmap-perl`, you should use `WORKDIR /jmap-perl` so that subsequent commands will be executed within the `jmap-perl` folder. `cd` within the run will only have an effect within that single RUN command.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Hey, it worked! Everything is proceeding now (I'm getting a new error this time, but I'll probably make a different post for it since it's a separate issue). Thanks again!